# sql for breaking one record into 2 records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables with data as below-
 table 1-

```
id name id_start_date
---------------------
345 Fiamma 1/01/1900
```

Table 2-

```
Change_Date Old_id New_id Users
-------------------------------
15/06/2017  123     345     abc@xyz.com
```

I'm looking for data as below-

```
id product_name start_date end_date
-----------------------------------    
123 Fiamma  1/01/1900   15/06/2017  
345 Fiamma  15/06/2017  31/12/2099
```

Basically I want to break the table 2 data into 2 records one with old id and the start and end dates for that id and the other with the new id with start and end dates.

Cheers

Comment: Might there be multiple entries in `Table 2` that relate to the same final item (e.g. a chain)? I assume for sanity's sake that it cannot contain a tree.

Comment: The table 2 just logs the date time when the old id changed to a new id and the first table just keeps the current value.

Comment: Yes, but I mean - might we have *another* row in that table that says that on 1st March 2010, id 6 changed to id 123? And if so, presumably that would then lead to 3 rows of output?

Answer (score 3):

```
select t2.old_id as id, t1.name as product_name, t1.start_date, t2.change_date as end_date
from table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.new_id

UNION

select t1.id as id, t1.name as product_name, t2.change_date, "" as end_date
from table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.new_id
```

Comment: That works, damn I used the wrong column name in first union. Thank you guys it worked.

Answer (score 0):

here is a test that you can run :

```
    create table #table1 
(
 id int,
 name varchar(50),
 start_date datetime
)

GO 

create table #table2
(
 change_date datetime, 
 Old_id int,
 New_id int,
 users varchar(50)
)

GO 

insert into #table1
values (345,'Fiamma','01/01/1900')


insert into #table2
values ('15/06/2017',123,345,'abc@xyz.com')


select * from #table1
select * from #table2


select t2.old_id as id, t1.name as product_name, t1.start_date as start_date, t2.change_date as end_date
from #table1 t1
INNER JOIN #table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.new_id

UNION

select t1.id as id, t1.name as product_name, t2.change_date as start_date , DATEADD(YEAR,+10,GETDATE()) as end_date
from #table1 t1
INNER JOIN #table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.new_id



drop table #table1
drop table #table2
```

[image]